# How to install files with .sh extension in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions

I have HP 32-bit laptop with ubuntu 16.04 lts OS. I want to install a software which comes with **.sh** (e.g. abcd.sh). Now I download this file in **Download** folder, and from terminal I go to this folder first  and ran:

```
$ cd Download
$ ./abcd.sh
bash: ./abcd.sh: Permission denied
```

Whats wrong with all those commands? How can I execute the file?

Comment: you just need to run `bash ./filename.sh`

Answer (score 5):

You need to make it executable first, run

```
chmod +x filename.sh
```

Then

```
./filename.sh
```

Comment: You don't need `sudo` for this.

Comment: `Verifying archive integrity. 
Extracting installer. ..............

CRITICAL FAILURE: PrintIntroduction() Error
  $ProductTitle not defined.



Installation failed. See /tmp/InstallErrors-8058. `

Comment: but still there is a problem as I stated above, now what is the problem ? @HaithamA.El-Ghareeb

Comment: Can you specify the software? Are you sure it is the same as your processor architecture?